# Truffle test is failing with "the tx doesn't have the correct nonce" error

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, truffle

I'm building the decentralized exchange app and currently covering my main contract with tests.
I've created several mocked tokens that are used during the test process (here is an example of one of them):

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Dai is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Dai Stablecoin", "DAI") {}

    function faucet(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do? I'm trying to mint tokens before each test execution.

Here is my test:

```js
const expectRevert = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers/src/expectRevert');

const Dai = artifacts.require('mocks/Dai.sol');
const Bat = artifacts.require('mocks/Bat.sol');
const Rep = artifacts.require('mocks/Rep.sol');
const Zrx = artifacts.require('mocks/Zrx.sol');
const Dex = artifacts.require('Dex.sol');

contract('Dex', (accounts) => {
  let tokenList;
  let dai, bat, rep, zrx, dex;

  const [trader1, trader2] = [accounts[1], accounts[2]];
  const [DAI, BAT, REP, ZRX] = ['DAI', 'BAT', 'REP', 'ZRX'].map((ticker) =>
    web3.utils.fromAscii(ticker)
  );

  beforeEach(async () => {
    tokenList = await Promise.all([Dai.new(), Bat.new(), Rep.new(), Zrx.new()]);
    [dai, bat, rep, zrx] = tokenList;

    dex = await Dex.new();

    await Promise.all([
      dex.addToken(DAI, dai.address),
      dex.addToken(BAT, bat.address),
      dex.addToken(REP, rep.address),
      dex.addToken(ZRX, zrx.address),
    ]);

    const amount = web3.utils.toWei('1000');
    const seedTokenBalance = async (token, trader) => {
      await token.faucet(trader, amount);
      await token.approve(dex.address, amount, {
        from: trader,
      });
    };

    await Promise.all(
      tokenList.map((token) => seedTokenBalance(token, trader1))
    );
    await Promise.all(
      tokenList.map((token) => seedTokenBalance(token, trader2))
    );
  });

  describe('deposit', () => {
    it('should deposit token', async () => {
      const amount = web3.utils.toWei('100');

      await dex.deposit(amount, DAI, {
        from: trader1,
      });

      const balance = await dex.traderBalances(trader1, DAI);

      assert(balance.toString() === amount);
    });

    it('should NOT deposit tokens if token does not exist', async () => {
      await expectRevert(
        dex.deposit(
          web3.utils.toWei('100'),
          web3.utils.fromAscii('TOKEN-DOES-NOT-EXIST'),
          { from: trader1 }
        ),
        'Token does not exist.'
      );
    });
  });
});
```

My test is constantly failing on that part of code:

```
await token.approve(dex.address, amount, {
        from: trader,
      });
```

with the following error:

> Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 1 tx has nonce of: 0 (vm hf=london -> block -> tx) -- Reason given: Custom error (could not decode).

**How can I fix this nonce inconsistency? Can anybody explain me the meaning of this error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggestion, you should have said that you were taking the "6 Figure Blockchain Developer" course from Eat The Blocks. By the way, I'm taking that course and I ran into the same issue trying to run the tests for the dex on my local machine.

I suspected that it was something related to concurrency, and I could finally get a solution. I don't fully understand what's happening and why the original code worked for Julien, but calling 'seedTokenBalance' method in an asynchronous way led to the errors. The reason is that 'map' array method, as well as 'forEach', doesn't await for the 'seedTokenBalance' async method to end its execution tasks ('token.faucet' and 'token.approve'), so all the methods are called in parallel and causing the errors.

I fixed it by replacing this:

```
await Promise.all(
  [dai, bat, rep, zrx].map(
    token => seedTokenBalance(token, trader1) 
  )
);
await Promise.all(
  [dai, bat, rep, zrx].map(
    token => seedTokenBalance(token, trader2) 
  )
);
```

With that:

```
let traders = [trader1, trader2];
let tokens = [dai, bat, rep, zrx];

for (const trader of traders) {
  for (const token of tokens) {
    await seedTokenBalance(token, trader);
  }
}
```

The "for of" loop iterates through traders and tokens and gives the possibility to await for the 'seedTokenBalance' method to end its execution, so all works without problems.

Maybe my reply is somewhat late, but I hope it will be useful to al people having this error.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! concurrency was actually a reason - you are totally correct